# Lower bound for a trace of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite Hermitian matrices. They need not necessarily commute. Let $a_m$ be the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

Is it true that 
$$
\text{Tr} (AB) \geq a_m \text{Tr} (B) 
$$

My attempt: let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be the eigenvalues (which are all real and positive) of $A$ and $B$. If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable by a similarity transformation then $
\text{Tr} (AB) = \sum_i a_i b_i \geq  a_m \sum_i b_i = a_m \text{Tr} (B) 
$. But is this generalizable to arbitrary $A$ and $B$ as laid out above?

Comment: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.636.8021&rep=rep1&type=pdf) looks relevant.

Comment: @PaulAljabar Thanks Paul this is a very nice source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that this is equivalent to proving that $\text{tr}((A - a_m I)B) \ge 0$. In fact the following more general claim is true:

> The trace of a product of two positive semidefinite matrices $A, B$ is nonnegative.

To see this we use the fact that there exist matrices $C, D$ such that $A = C^{\dagger} C, B = D^{\dagger} D$ where $^{\dagger}$ denotes the adjoint. Then we compute that

$$\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(C^{\dagger} CD^{\dagger} D) = \text{tr}(DC^{\dagger} CD^{\dagger}) = \text{tr}(E^{\dagger} E) \ge 0$$

where $E = CD^{\dagger}$.